# High pressure RC fuel pump

Tags: motor, aircraft, fuel

How many PSI do the best (electric) fuel pumps have? For RC jet turbines I found 12 bar the highest. Are there any better?

Comment: Can you provide more details as to the application of this electric pump? What is it pumping fuel to, how much fuel does it need to move at what rate,  what type of fuel is it handling, where exactly is this pump going to be, etc.